# php, sql , получить данные в той же таблице по индификатору

Tags: php, sql, yii2

у меня есть данная таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function actionLocality()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->get();
            $s = trim($data['keyword']);

                       $locality = Locality::find()->select(['title', 'type'])
                ->where(['like', 'title', $s])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();

            if (!empty($locality)) {
                return JSON::encode($locality);
            }
        }

        return JSON::encode(null);
    }
}
```

столбец partner_id хранит индификаторы(id) этой же таблицы

Я хочу получить также информацию по parent_id

Для примера: я хочу получить информацию по ID 51, у него parent_id  30110, то также взять и информацию по данному индификатору(30110)

Не делая циклов , а если можно одним запросом (если это возможно)

Comment: Вам нужны JOIN https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: я join смогу обратиться таблицы locality к locality? ( вроде нельзя)

Comment: Всё можно, добавляем алиасы чтобы не было конфликта имен

Comment: клонку type в другую таблицу вынеси))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модель таблицы добавь метод:

```
public function getParent()
{ 
      return $this->hasOne(self::className,['id' =>'parent_id']);
}
```

Потом в нужном месте вызываешь:

```
$locality ->parent->title
```

Ну или в виджетах:

```
parent.title
```

Единственное, убери asArray() из запроса. Тогда сможешь обращаться к объекту $locality.
Теперь сможешь получать в месте с обьектом $locality под id =51, объект под id=30110. А также смотреть у объекта id=30110 его parentId. Выглядеть будет

```
parent.parent.title
```

Yii поддерживает кучу уровней вложенности.
А если нужно будет перевести в массив используй ArrayHelper.

```
$locality = Locality::find()
            ->where(['like', 'title', $s])
            ->all();

if (!empty($locality)) {
            return JSON::encode(
ArrayHelper::toArray($locality, [
'app\models\Locality' => [
        'id',
        'title',
        'parent.id',
        'parent.title',
        'parent.parent_id', //Если нужно вывести другие аттрибуты 30110
        'length' => function ($locality) {
            return strlen($locality->id);
        },
    ],
])
);
        }
```

Comment: я суть понял но как это подвязать к моему запросу?

Comment: А куда ты выводиш данные? В Grid?

Comment: Я тебе написал полную подвязку к твоему запросу. Когда ты обращаешься к модели, это значить ты обращаешься к объекту(таблица) locality с объектами(строками) содержащими поля id,. title и т.д + методы и своиства описанные в модели Locality в папке app/models/Locality.php.

Comment: нет не в grid, это у меня идет ajax запрос в AjaxController

Comment: Напиши код action куда делаешь запрос и что хочешь получить в ответ

Comment: обновил вопрос, вкоде добавил полностью все

Comment: Изменил ответ под твою ситуацию